# What is considered enough commenting?

Tags: java, coding-style, comments

My computer science course wants me to start descriptively commenting out my code so that the teacher and other students can better understand it while reading it. Being 50% lazy and 50% elitist, I don't want to have to comment out every line just so that people can understand my code. I don't want to comment out every method unless that is really necessary either (the teacher only requires what is necessary for him to understand going on without having to try to interpret individual lines of code). What is accepted in the computer science universe as "enough commenting?"

Comment: There is an important difference between "commenting" and "commenting-out".

Comment: It doesn't really matter what we think, what you need to do is the expected level of commenting, and like in the work place, this entirely depends on how your team is expected to work.  BTW some code is self explanatory e.g. getters and setters,some code need a lot more comments than code to explain what it does.

Comment: `What is accepted in the computer science universe as "enough commenting?"` There is no single answer to this. To this *specific* question, the answer is "as much as your teacher wants/requires". Out in the real world, that is determined by your employer, your coworkers, and your own experience as a developer. This question is probably not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: As a ~20 year veteran, I practice a self-documenting code approach. I will only comment on something I have done if it might not be obvious to the majority of people that might work in my code later. I strive to write code that is self-documenting by using descriptive variables, classes and methods. 

If this is for a class however, I would suggest following the instructors words to the letter. If something is unclear, have them clarify it for you before you go too far and realize it is wrong.

Comment: @admdrew If it's for yourself, you put no comments, and realise the next day that you can't remember what some code did, but it works, and you promise never to touch it :D

Comment: @AntonH Haha, agreed. I've called my past self an idiot many many times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally accepted guidelines for commenting are:

- Non-trivial classes should have JavaDoc describing their usage / purpose.  Documenting an object's thread safety is also frequently useful.
- Non-trivial / non-obvious methods based on the method name should have JavaDoc.  Ideally any requirements on the parameters should be noted (behaviour in regards to nulls etc), as well as any modifications to passed in Objects.  Good rule of thumb is to answer:

  - What does this method require
  - What does it produce / guarantee (and when does it throw an exception)
  - What (if anything) does it modify
- Any complicated or non-obvious lines of code should be commented

  - Where did this magic constant come from
  - Why is this being done (if not obvious)
- Class variables can be commented when necessary.  This is less standard, but it is sometimes useful to comment variables to indicate what it is to be used for.

Avoid comments that merely repeat what the code is doing.  E.g.

```
// Set x to 4 before the loop
x = 4;
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
```

But, if appropriate, comment why it is being done:

```
// Set x to 4 since we are guaranteed to only have 4 threads
x = 4;
for ...
```

**At a minimum, you should have good method comments (consider this the most important), and rough overview comments for your classes.**  I would consider anything less than this to be unprofessional and a reason for rejecting a code review.

Answer (score 0):

In Java comments are used to generate a javadoc from the source code you have written. Format your comments according javadoc spec. That's enough for commenting in Java, other comments are optional and how someone mentioned comments are versus commented out code. If you keep such code in files you'd better leave a reasonable comment (i.e. referencing some issue, etc.). Note that using Java naming conventions and properly named Java elements greatly reduce needs for commenting inside the code. These comments are only intended for uses who will proof read or debug your code are optional as I mentioned above. Other optional comments are project related and tagged for example `todo`. You should concentrate more attention on javadoc comments, as general rule are placed on all public methods and classes including interfaces. if your class implements some interface method then you should not duplicate comment there, just reference a corresponding interface method comment.